# Multiple purpose action. What are you doing?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> When you do this action,  there could be different deductions:
>
> Maybe you're doing a chore empirical,  giving instructions to your
> vehicle.
>
> Maybe you are very cruel,  or try to establish your rule.
>
> Or a perversion in the mind,  pain and pleasure dost 'em bind.
>
> To return to simpler sweetness,  give that mixture its completeness.
>
> Last, and hardly, you are curious  sound barrier breaking usurious.

Tip:

> A famous fictional adventurer had one.

Comment: "putting your foot down" would work for some of the clues but I don't think that's it.. Maybe along with fetish? I give up

Comment: @pkr298 ahh, that reminded me of "in these shoes" by Kirsty MAcColl. Not relevant to intended answer though.

Comment: @George would you mind adding some hints??

Comment: @Bass Errors not captured by autocorrect are the worse :(

Comment: great riddle! I wish I had come across it sooner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Whip

Maybe you're doing a chore empirical, giving instructions to your vehicle.

> Not sure about the chore empirical, but you can whip your car back and forth

Maybe you are very cruel, or try to establish your rule.

> You can whip people with your words, or "whip" them into shape -- get them inline. Usually when you do this, you are in a position of power/leadership/control.

Or a perversion in the mind, pain and pleasure dost 'em bind.

> S&M 'nough said

To return to simpler sweetness, give that mixture its completeness.

> When baking, you whip together the ingredients to form the right consistencies and mix everything together properly.

Last, and hardly, you are curious sound barrier breaking usurious.

> Whips definitely break the sound barrier.

The tip:

> Indiana Jones always had a whip

Comment: To be honest, you even went further than intended! Line 2 was referring to a horse car "vehicle", and line 3 was just having the plain act of whipping with a whip in mind. I guess thanks for enrichening it!